pnpm and npm cannnot start a vite server nor install package, with error code 3221225477
The problem is that it do it's job flawlessly yesterday, and somehow don't work now. The only possible relevance in the process is a python backend server I tested, which did not use the same port anyways. The problem only happen on my machine, and works perfect when on other machine. So I'd like to ask how to identify what is in my way and try to solve them.
What I tried:
I've tried simular posts' solution such as adjust firewall, reinstall node and npm, reinstall packages and clear cache, but none worked and I had no clue even if I looked through the script it tries to run.
These are the error I received:
node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.24.2/node_modules/esbuild: Running postinstall script...

node_modules/.pnpm/esbuild@0.24.2/node_modules/esbuild: Running postinstall script, failed in 101ms

.../esbuild@0.24.2/node_modules/esbuild postinstall$ node install.js

└─ Failed in 101ms at (...)\GitHub\2025-AI-glucose\glutose-FE\node_modules\.pnpm\esbuild@0.24.2\node_modules\esbuild

\esbuild@0.21.5\node_modules\esbuild

node_modules/.pnpm/vue-demi@0.14.10_vue@3.5.13/node_modules/vue-demi: Running postinstall script, failed in 87msE  Command failed with exit code 3221225477.

.../node_modules/vue-demi postinstall$ node -e "try{require('./scripts/postinstall.js')}catch(e){}"

└─ Failed in 87ms at (...)\GitHub\2025-AI-glucose\glutose-FE\node_modules\.pnpm\vue-demi@0.14.10_vue@3.5.13\node_modules\vue-demi

ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 3221225477.

EDIT
And here's what npm reported
2905 info run esbuild@0.21.5 postinstall node_modules/esbuild node install.js
2906 info run vue-demi@0.14.10 postinstall node_modules/vue-demi node -e "try{require('./scripts/postinstall.js')}catch(e){}"
2907 info run esbuild@0.21.5 postinstall { code: 3221225477, signal: null }
2908 info run vue-demi@0.14.10 postinstall { code: 3221225477, signal: null }
2909 warn cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
2909 warn cleanup   [
2909 warn cleanup     '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\creap\\OneDrive\\文件\\GitHub\\2025-AI-glucose\\glutose-FE\\node_modules\\vue-demi',
2909 warn cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\creap\OneDrive\文件\GitHub\2025-AI-glucose\glutose-FE\node_modules\vue-demi'] {
2909 warn cleanup       errno: -4082,
2909 warn cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
2909 warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
2909 warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\creap\\OneDrive\\文件\\GitHub\\2025-AI-glucose\\glutose-FE\\node_modules\\vue-demi'
2909 warn cleanup     }
2909 warn cleanup   ],
2909 warn cleanup   [
2909 warn cleanup     '\\\\?\\C:\\Users\\creap\\OneDrive\\文件\\GitHub\\2025-AI-glucose\\glutose-FE\\node_modules',
2909 warn cleanup     [Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rmdir 'C:\Users\creap\OneDrive\文件\GitHub\2025-AI-glucose\glutose-FE\node_modules\vue-demi'] {
2909 warn cleanup       errno: -4082,
2909 warn cleanup       code: 'EBUSY',
2909 warn cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
2909 warn cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\creap\\OneDrive\\文件\\GitHub\\2025-AI-glucose\\glutose-FE\\node_modules\\vue-demi'
2909 warn cleanup     }
2909 warn cleanup   ]
2909 warn cleanup ]


What are npm and node versions? What is the output with npm? Try to clear npm cache and make a fresh copy of the project and reinstall deps, i.e remove node_modules and keep package lock, in case there's one. " works perfect when on other machine" - how do os and node versions differ? 3221225477 is windows ACCESS_VIOLATION error, so it's possibly not related to node at all. Tried to reboot at least?

@EstusFlask node 22.12.2 and 11.0.0 npm. I will put npm log on the post if I can find them soon. The OS on other machine is the same build and architecture, So there is no diffrence as far as I could think of. Reboot and switch user does not work too

I'd suggest to stick to npm 10 to not cause additional problems. But it's most likely not related.  In addition to the previous comment, try also installing another node lts version (20) and running it as admin. The other causes are less convenient https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/inside/c0000005

@EstusFlask The problem disappeared after I installed node 20 lts, I rebuilt my packages. No additional privilege is required. I'd assume it is a problem of the newer version not compatible with my modules. Thank you for these instruction. Wish you have a nice year ahead.

Same to you. Glad it was that simple. I could understand why esbuild, but vue-demi is cryptic at least. Could be a bug in node. I'd suggest to try other versions of 22 and 23 if you're forced to use the latest

The solution is simple. And I tried to find some potential cause of it worked then did't work overnight.
The solution
The solution is provided by @Estus Flask . I removed my existing node installation (22 lts) and used node 20 lts instead. with both npm and node are lower version, the script that was previously not able to run passed. I would suggest future me or anyone struggle to do the same (use a slightly older version of npm and node), delete your node-module, then rebuild your modules.
The potential cause
I usually mindlessly update my node whenever there's notification in my terminal. Seems like it is not a good thing. Please avoid it if you like to do whatever they said in terminal like I did.
